# Is it possible for Vue.js to add data to a file in AWS S3 bucket?

Tags: vue.js

I am developing a simple application by Vue.js, which is trying to combine couples of strings as a array and name it as a new name. Now the problem is how can I save the combined data to some place so that I can access the combined data in the future. I am expecting I can save the data into AWS S3, however local is acceptable(such as `public` folder in the Vue.js code structure)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can't save data into anything local from the client application (browser-run), unless it's installed as a standalone. What you need is to use AWS S3 JS SDK to upload directly into the bucket.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I am planning to develop a full-stack app to achieve my goals.

Comment: You don't have to have a backend if the only thing you do is getting files uploaded and then providing access to the same media via the frontend. All you need is to mind the security implications so the bucket is not getting filled with some random stuff and someone accessing files they are not meant to.